# Show that if $X$ is path connected then $X$ is the union of a collection of paths

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ denote paths in $X$.

Assume that $X$ is non-empty and is Path Connected. Show that there exists some collection $\Gamma$, of paths in $X$, which all share the same starting point, such that $X=\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\gamma ([0,1])$

I think I have found a solution by fixing $x\in X$ and then letting the path between $x$ and $y$ belong to $\Gamma$ for all $y\in X$. Im pretty sure this works but it seems a little messy and I know is not the most compact solution. How can I come up with something more elegant/compact?

Comment: Just let $\Gamma$ be the set of all paths starting at a fixed $x_0$. No need to choose one for each target. You can then show that $X = \{ \gamma(1) : \gamma\in\Gamma \} = \bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} \gamma(\{1\}) \subseteq \bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} \gamma([0,1]) \subseteq X$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but could you explain how this shows $X=\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\gamma ([0,1])$. I read it as $X\subseteq\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\gamma ([0,1])$

Comment: Equality follows since $A\subseteq B \subseteq A$ is equivalent to $A=B$.

Comment: Of course, thanks

Comment: In my opinion, Connor's approach is more intuitive and understandable at once. Moreover, Christoph's collection $\Gamma$ contains much more paths than Connor's. So, it is less "compact".

Comment: I did notice that. I think Christoph's is easier to write down formally. I did think about a solution which goes through each $y\in X$ and fist checks if $y$ is already contained in some path already in $\Gamma$ but I think obtaining a compact solution like this is maybe not worth the extra work required

Comment: @ConnorBishop, there is no "the" path between $x$ and $y$. There is just **a** path. You can let $\Gamma$ contain a path from $x$ to $y$.